# (Illustrator) How to edit text that is transformed into shape of arc?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, text, text-on-path

I'm finding it difficult to edit text that has been shaped into form of a arc.

I would like to change typeface, font size, bend of the arc.
However, whatever I'm trying to change doesn't make any sense.

All changes are visible in completely different scale than in normal text edit "mode".
Font size change is either very subtle or on contrary very radical even though change in px count is the very same.

Can't find how to modify the arc? Or at least how to do it so that whole visual element doesn't change into so to speak three-eyed-fish.

And can't really imagine that I would need to create everything from the scratch if I need to change one or two settings of a "text element"?

I'm using CS5.

EDIT2:
Font size 72px
[image]

Font size 6px
[image]

Comment: Looks like Warp effect may have been applied. Is your text still shaped when toggling into "Path mode"? If not, open "Appearance" Panel and modify the Warp effect. If not, please provide screenshots: normal + path modes

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Appearance panel with that text object selected? There are a few ways to create that arc and the Appearance panel would show which method is in use.

Comment: Maybe you missed it... **Can you post a screenshot of the Appearance panel with that text object selected?**

Comment: I had to remove that image due to link limitations. However, it seems that this is just overly complex and it would be easier to just create an arc and use type on a path tool. Although, it did show some other problems that make it hard to modify text and testing different sizes. Quite expensive software but such simple tasks like these seem overly complex...

Comment: I think you just don't understand enough how Illustrator works; it is quite straight forward to manipulate text into a simple arch like that. Perhaps you should take some time checking tutorials on these operations, there is plenty of documentation on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the effect(s) from the text frame's Appearance palette? It actually looks like there may be overlapping/interfering effects. The aim here would be to return the text to a normal state that can be modified, and then re-apply the warp in a more controlled manner.

In my tests, resizing warped text does not act as shown in your screenshots. Is it possible your Character palette scaling is not at 100%? I've circled these in 
the screenshot below.

[image: Remove Warp from text]

I have received files in the past with corrupted text frames, so it's not out of the question that you have one of these on your hands. The usual tell for corrupt text frames is that they reset to 50 pt font size no matter what, and this does look similar.

If these suggestions do not solve the problem, you may have to recreate the text anew or kick it back.

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe Illustrator,
You can Double click on transformed text so it will be in isolation mode.

now single click on text.

Done,
You can Edit it.

Comment: If I do this and change font size from 6px to 60px it changes only few pixels on screen and basically nudges a bit upwards but nothing else. I'll add an example with images.

Comment: I think This will help you much better way:
This is little different from arc. but more powerful if you get it done right:

this is how to use envelope distort within Adobe Illustrator to create extremely simple yet powerful effects on type! The end results only create a few seconds to create, and allow you to change and edit your type even after you've applied the effect.

See this: **[link](https://youtu.be/9KPHYfDVq_0)**

I hope this will surely help.

Comment: @LuciferMorningStar comments are not for answering questions; flesh the contents of that link into a proper answer! If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: i'll keep that in mind next time. thanks @Luciano